# Vuex State data is not persisting?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm working on admin panel in `vuejs` and using `vuex` for state management.

**store/module/home/home.js:**

```
import instance from "../../../services/Http";


const state = {

    usersCount: 0,
    customersCount: 0,
    chefsCount: 0,
    driversCount: 0,
    Users: [],
};

const getters = {
    Userscount: state => state.usersCount,
    Customerscount: state => state.customersCount,
    Chefscount: state => state.chefsCount,
    Driverscount: state => state.driversCount,
    users: state => state.Users,
};

const actions = {

    getStats({commit})
    {
        instance.get('admin/stats').then(res => commit('setStats', res.data));
    },

    getUsers({commit})
    {
        instance.get('admin/users').then(res => commit('setUsers', res.data));
    }
};

const mutations = {
    setStats:(state, data) => {
        state.usersCount = data.usersCount;
        state.customersCount = data.customersCount;
        state.chefsCount = data.chefsCount;
        state.driversCount =  data.driversCount;
    },

    setUsers:(state, data) => { state.Users = data.users}
};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

and then i'm calling `getStats` and `getUsers` `actions` in two different components in `created method` of respective `components`.

The issue is that `getStats` and `setStats` is executed but it does not set the data, but `getUsers` and `setUsers` is working as expected.

**src/components/layouts/Widgets.vue:**

```
<template>
    <!-- Widgets  -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="stat-widget-five">
                        <div class="stat-icon dib flat-color-1">
<!--                            <i class="pe-7s-cash"></i>-->
                            <i class="pe-7s-users"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="stat-content">
                            <div class="text-left dib">
                                <div class="stat-text"><span class="count">{{ Userscount }}</span></div>
                                <div class="stat-heading">Total Users</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="stat-widget-five">
                        <div class="stat-icon dib flat-color-2">
<!--                            <i class="pe-7s-cart"></i>-->
                            <i class="pe-7s-users"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="stat-content">
                            <div class="text-left dib">
                                <div class="stat-text"><span class="count">{{ Chefscount }}</span></div>
                                <div class="stat-heading">Total Chefs</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="stat-widget-five">
                        <div class="stat-icon dib flat-color-8">
<!--                            <i class="pe-7s-browser"></i>-->
                            <i class="pe-7s-users"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="stat-content">
                            <div class="text-left dib">
                                <div class="stat-text"><span class="count">{{ Customerscount }}</span></div>
                                <div class="stat-heading">Total Customers</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="stat-widget-five">
                        <div class="stat-icon dib flat-color-4">
                            <i class="pe-7s-users"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="stat-content">
                            <div class="text-left dib">
                                <div class="stat-text"><span class="count">{{ Driverscount }}</span></div>
                                <div class="stat-heading">Total Drivers</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Widgets -->
</template>

<script>
    import {mapActions,mapGetters} from 'vuex';

    export default {
        name: "Widgets",
        created() {
            this.getStats();
        },
        computed: mapGetters(['Userscount','Customerscount','Chefscount','Driverscount']),
        methods:{
            ...mapActions(['getStats'])
        },
    }
</script>
```

i'have also attached images showing of `vue js dev tools` for `vuex` that data is stored in state but it is not being displayed.

[image]

[image]

edit-1:

**setStats-after console.log**

```
{usersCount: 12, customersCount: 4, chefsCount: 7, driversCount: 0, postsCount: 22}chefsCount: 7customersCount: 4driversCount: 0postsCount: 22usersCount: 12__proto__: Object
```

Edit-2:

`vuex binding` `widgets components`

[image]

Edit-3:

**Store/index.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import auth from "./modules/auth/auth";
import home from "./modules/home/home";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
    auth,
    home

  }
});
```

**sr/main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    // this route requires auth, check if logged in
    // if not, redirect to login page.
    if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn)
    {
      next({
        name: 'login',
      })
    }
    else
    {
      next();
    }
  }
  else if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.Visitor)) {
    if (store.getters.isLoggedIn)
    {
      next({
        name: 'home',
      })
    }
    else
    {
      next();
    }
  }
  else
  {
    next()
  }
});

new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

**src/components/layout/Main.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div class="Main">
        <SideBar/>
        <div id="right-panel" class="right-panel">
            <Header/>
            <!-- Content -->
            <div class="content">
                <div class="animated fadeIn">
                    <Widgets/>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <Users/>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import SideBar from "./SideBar";
    import Header from "./Header";
    import Footer from "./Footer";
    import Widgets from "./Widgets";
    import Users from "../users/Users";

    export default {
        name: "Main",
        components: {Users, Widgets, Footer, Header, SideBar}
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    #weatherWidget .currentDesc {
        color: #ffffff!important;
    }
    .traffic-chart {
        min-height: 335px;
    }
    #flotPie1  {
        height: 150px;
    }
    #flotPie1 td {
        padding:3px;
    }
    #flotPie1 table {
        top: 20px!important;
        right: -10px!important;
    }
    .chart-container {
        display: table;
        min-width: 270px ;
        text-align: left;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #flotLine5  {
        height: 105px;
    }

    #flotBarChart {
        height: 150px;
    }
    #cellPaiChart{
        height: 160px;
    }
</style>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(data)` within `setStats()`? Does `data` have the expected values? Also, how are you trying to display the data? Are you using `computed` properties?

Comment: i've updated my question with the answer to you comment

Comment: @glitch it's showing cotrect data

Comment: Are you using `computed` properties to display the data?

Comment: yes i'm using computed properties

Comment: @glitch updated my question with component code

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. I tried to replicate it in [the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-1j25v) and it works. There must be something else happening. If you look up your "Widgets" component in Vue Dev Tools, does it show "vuex bindings" in detail view ?

Comment: I agree with Michal. The code works in a sandbox. @SalmanZafar , if u could provide a sanbox with your entire code (App.vue, main.js etc), it will help in finding out the issue.

Comment: @MichalLevý I've updated the question with `vuex binding` `widgets components` screenshot

Comment: @SalmanZafar That doesn't make sense at all. Please check again that the code you posted for `Widgets.vue` is what you are really using. I'v deleted previous sandbox by mistake - you can check [new one](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-state-data-is-not-persisting-b98pe). Its working. Check differences. Mayby post the content of your main Vuex configuration file....

Comment: @MichalLevý i've updated the question with all the relevant code.

Comment: You are importing your `Widgets` component inside your `src/components/layout/Main.vue` as `import Widgets from "./Widgets";` so the path to component should be `src/components/layout/Widgets.vue` but in your question it says `src/components/Widgets.vue`. Is that correct ?

Comment: @MichalLevý a good catch Thanks. i've updated it as it was typo error

Comment: well I was hoping that maybe there are two `Widgets` components in your solution (by mistake during some refactoring) and you are loading different (old) one than the one you are showing in your question. Because the component in question works just fine. Are you 100% sure the code of `Widgets` component is actually used ?

Comment: Yes. There is only widget component in entire app. Sometimes (rarely) it's shows the data but most of the time it doesn't.

Comment: @SalmanZafar I am once again requesting you to create a sandbox, run your code, reproduce the issue and share it here. Michal as already shared 2 code samples that work perfectly fine.
You cannot expect people to copy your code and replicate your issue. It's your job to replicate the issue and share it in ur question.

Comment: Sure i'll do it and share it here

Comment: Your getters aren't computed values. Have you tried using `...mapState` instead?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add "..." before the 'mapGetters', "...mapGetters"

Comment: He's right - it's not a problem because getters from `mapGetters` are only computed properties he's using. In that case you don't need spread operator....

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem would be solved by implementing the strict-mode in Vuex, by the way, it's turned off by default.
take a look here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html

Comment: unfortunately it didn't still same issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `mapState` instead of `mapGetters`? As your values are just being updated, but your getters aren't computed values, they just map to your state.

Instead of:

```
<script>
    import {mapActions,mapGetters} from 'vuex';

    export default {
        name: "Widgets",
        created() {
            this.getStats();
        },
        computed: mapGetters(['Userscount','Customerscount','Chefscount','Driverscount']),
        methods:{
            ...mapActions(['getStats'])
        },
    }
</script>
```

Maybe try:

```
<script>
    import {mapActions,mapGetters} from 'vuex';

    export default {
        name: "Widgets",
        created() {
            this.getStats();
        },
        computed: mapState({
           Userscount: state => state.home.Userscount,
           Customerscount: state => state.home.Customerscount,
           Chefscount: state => state.home.Chefscount, 
           Driverscount: state => state.home.Drivers.count
        }),
        methods:{
            ...mapActions(['getStats'])
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: still same issue